# how can I set the lowest frame rate possible on my monitor? is it safe to make tests with it?

Tags: 20.04

I found that if I lower the FPS on games, my old gfx card wont heat up so much.

But if I try this, I get that error below (the name ending is a $RANDOM as  `xrandr -delmode` does not work):

```
$ "xrandr" "--newmode" "1368x768-12.0019866" "15.75" "1368" "1408" "1536" "1704" "768" "771" "781" "784" "-hsync" "+vsync"
$ "xrandr" "--addmode" "HDMI-0" "1368x768-12.0019866"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

xrandr says:

```
HDMI-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 609mm x 347mm
   1366x768      59.79*+
   1920x1080     59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```

so for 1366x768 there is only one refresh available: 59.79

by what I read, the refresh must be between the acceptable range, so I would need to copy  `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf` somewhere and add the below lines generated with nvidia-settings right?

```
Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "SAMSUNG"
    HorizSync       15.0 - 68.0
    VertRefresh     24.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection
```

The `VertRefresh     24.0 - 75.0`, can I tweak it to `VertRefresh     10.0 - 75.0`?
Doing that could mess my monitor (hardware) or I just need to revert to a valid config like `...;sleep 10;xrandr -s 1366x768`

I also read `gtf 1366 768 15` will give me imprecise results, why? and `cvt 1366 768 15` would be more reliable.

So in short, what can I do? can I try any very low VertRefresh I want?
How can I do it? where should i put the VertRefresh config as there is no xorg.conf at /etc/X11 anymore on 20.04?

Comment: Changing the refresh rate of the display isn't going to help unless you're using vsync. Even then, it doesn't make sense to change the hardware refresh rate. If you want to reduce the frame rate in specific applications, use the application settings to do so. Most games where frame rate can be an issue will allow you to set a frame rate cap.

Comment: yeah, that is the idea, the game wont allow custom fps cap, and explains it will cap to vsync!

Comment: Most displays will not accept any refresh rate except the native refresh rate. Hardware like CPUs and GPUs are expected to be able to run at 100% with adequate cooling, so if your hardware is overheating then the bigger problem is the cooling. You may need to remove dust or if the device is several years old, you may need to reapply thermal compound